# Responsive Design: reduce breakpoints

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive, breakpoints, responsiveness

I always wondered if we could reduce breakpoints in a responsive design.

Here is a simple example. I have a form containing text inputs. The normal way for responsiveness would be to have many breakpoints for example large laptop, laptop, tablet, large phone, small phone to have the nicest width for the text inputs. But would it be possible rather to have for the text inputs width something like:

- If screen width > 1024 -> width: 40%
- If screen width < 481 -> width: 80%
- For any screen width in between, use the linear interpolation (width in between 40% to 80% depending of the screen width)

Is it possible to do so with css?

Comment: SO is a Q&A site where one asks a specific question that can return a fact-based answer. This question seems to be asking for opinion and discussion. [ask]

Comment: @Rob Ok I will update my question to ask more for a specific answer to the example I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the given percentages to actual pixel values:

- 80% of 480px yields 384,8 =>  **p1( 480,385)**
- 40% of 1024px yields 409,6 => **p2(1024,410)**

Both rounded up to an integer as part of a pixel counts as a full pixel (use the decimal values instead if so required).

Then with above points **p1(x1,y1)** and **p2(x2,y2)** use the *point slope form* of

Linear Equation **y = mx + b**, which is **y − y1 = m(x − x1)**

- y = required result
- m = (y2 − y1) / (x2 − x1)
- x = 100vw
- b = y1 − m × x1

=> substituted: **y = y1 + (y2 − y1) / (x2 − x1) × (x − x1)**

Final result using foremetioned points: **y = 0.04595589x + 362.941177**

Convert to CSS: `calc(0.04595589 * 100vw + 362.941177px)`

=> simplified `calc(4.596vw + 362.942px)` (rounded up to three decimals precision)

*Reference: [MathIsFun: Point-Slope Equation of a Line](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-point-slope.html)*

**Extra**: Linear Equation **y=mx+b** can be used to calculate the value of any size property relative to the viewport size.

E.g. for my base font size I usually use CSS `html { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem) }` using points p1(320,14) and p2(1280,20). This makes `1rem` vary from `14px` on a `320px` to `20px` on a `1280px` viewport minimum size.

**Snippet**

```css
input[type="text"] {
    /* using y=mx+b with points p1(480,385) p2(1024,410) */
    /* y = 0.04595589x + 362.941177 */
    width: clamp(385px, 4.596vw + 362.942px, 410px); /* with clamp() */
    width: calc(4.596vw + 362.942px);                /* without...   */
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="text">

<p>Check with DevTools:</p>
<p>At viewport width 480px, input width must be 385px.
<br>At viewport width 1024px, input width must be 410px.</p>
<p>(Provided browser zoom factor and font size settings are set to default.)</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use media-queries to achieve these conditions. Like this:

```css
input{
    width: 40%;
}
@media (max-width: 1024px){
    input{
        max-width: 80%;
        min-width: 40%;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 481px){
    input{
        width: 80%;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="type here">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not think of using a combination of max-width and min-width, but it does not seem to do the trick. In the code snippet, I don't see any linear interpolation between the two breakpoints.